# how to support touchscreen connected with a serial cable

Tags: android

I am transplanting android to my stb, and I want stb could support touchscreen.

the touchscreen connecte to stb with a serial cable

I am trying to support it in native layer, but I don't know how to do.

I have tryed the following method: using "process" function in inputread.h, but inputreader is not singleton, I can't get it's pointer or refrence.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough task.

First, you must well know the details of how a touch event is processed. To understand a standard touch event format typically in /dev/input/xxx.

Second, you need to figure out how your current serial touch panel works, what is the out put format of this device.

If your tty device output the same format of a standard touch event, you can simply configure the HAL to open the specific device and all will be settled.

Else, if it is not a standard touch event format, two options for you:

```
1. Adapt to this format in event hub layer
2. Transform this format in driver layer
```

Both are not very easy.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I had tried write /dev/input/eventXXX with InputEvent struct in linux/input.h, and it is work.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 1,I had tried write /dev/input/eventXXX with InputEvent struct in linux/input.h, and it is work.but the file eventXXX is generating automatical when mouse is plug in.what I want is no mouse device and there is eventXXX file. 2,I know the output format of touchscreen, it is not standard touch event.do you have some reference about two options you suggested. thank you agian.

Comment: Sorry, I have no reference or sample code for your question. Since the format of your serial touch panel output is very specific, there is no universal solution. I think option 2 is more suitable for you.